# UseEffect() of child getting called more than once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Problem:** UseEffect of Child widget is getting executed thrice even though i have given empty dependency array. For simplicity of code I have omitted some logic in Parent component that loads childWidget dynamically. If needed I can add that too here but is there any issue like conflicts of forwardRef and UseEffect Or something else is missing.

**Code:**

```
const ChildWidget = (props) =>{
useEffect(()=>{ console.log('ChildWidget useEffect func')},[])

return (<div>ChildWidget</div>)
}

const Parent = forwardRef((props, ref) =>{
useImperativeHandler(ref,()=>({
show(){.. //some code ..}
hide(){.. //some code ..}
}))

useEffect(()=>{console.log('Parent UseEffect')},[]);

return(
<ChildWidget a={props.a} b={props.b}/>
)
})
```

**Result:**
UseEffect of Parent is always called once but of that of child it is called thrice.

Answer (score -3):

**Try this once...**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandler } from 'react';

const ChildWidget = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ChildWidget useEffect func');
    // Add any code you want to run when the component mounts or updates
    // If you need to run code only when the component mounts, remove the dependency array []
  });

  return <div>ChildWidget</div>;
};

const Parent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandler(ref, () => ({
    show() {
      // Some code for the show function
    },
    hide() {
      // Some code for the hide function
    },
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Parent UseEffect');
    // Add any code you want to run when the component mounts or updates
    // If you need to run code only when the component mounts, remove the dependency array []
  });

  return <ChildWidget a={props.a} b={props.b} />;
});

export default Parent;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).